# Amazon EC2 Minecraft Server - Cannot run mc commands, only runs bash commands

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terminal, minecraft

Normally, manually using SSH to connect to my EC2 server and then running this command will start the Minecraft server and allow me to enter in Minecraft commands

```
java -Xmx7G -Xms7G -jar vanilla-1.18.2.jar nogui
```

However, I have created a batch file on my computer to automate both launching the EC2 server (using AWSCLI) and the Minecraft server.

```
aws ec2 start-instances --instance-ids <INSTANCE ID>
ssh -i "Minecraft SMP.pem" ec2-user@DNS "cd MC/Server ; bash | java -Xmx7G -Xms7G -jar vanilla-1.18.2.jar nogui"
```

Line 1 launches the EC2 server using AWS's Command Line Interface. Line 2 connects to it from my pc, changes the directory to the MC server, and then runs it.

However, once the server is started, I can only enter in bash commands into the terminal-- not Minecraft commands.

Is there any way to "change the focus" onto the Minecraft server?

This is what happens when I run the batch file.

```
G:\Games\MC\My SMP>aws ec2 start-instances --instance-ids <INSTANCE ID>
{
    "StartingInstances": [
        {
            "CurrentState": {
                "Code": 16,
                "Name": "running"
            },
            "InstanceId": "<INSTANCE ID>",
            "PreviousState": {
                "Code": 16,
                "Name": "running"
            }
        }
    ]
}


G:\Games\MC\My SMP>ssh -i "Minecraft SMP.pem" ec2-user@DNS "cd MC/Server ; bash | java -Xmx7G -Xms7G -jar vanilla-1.18.2.jar nogui"
Starting net.minecraft.server.Main
[16:53:33] [ServerMain/INFO]: Environment: authHost='https://authserver.mojang.com', accountsHost='https://api.mojang.com', sessionHost='https://sessionserver.mojang.com', servicesHost='https://api.minecraftservices.com', name='PROD'
[16:53:36] [ServerMain/WARN]: Ambiguity between arguments [teleport, location] and [teleport, destination] with inputs: [0.1 -0.5 .9, 0 0 0]
[16:53:36] [ServerMain/WARN]: Ambiguity between arguments [teleport, location] and [teleport, targets] with inputs: [0.1 -0.5 .9, 0 0 0]
[16:53:36] [ServerMain/WARN]: Ambiguity between arguments [teleport, destination] and [teleport, targets] with inputs: [Player, 0123, @e, dd12be42-52a9-4a91-a8a1-11c01849e498]
[16:53:36] [ServerMain/WARN]: Ambiguity between arguments [teleport, targets] and [teleport, destination] with inputs: [Player, 0123, dd12be42-52a9-4a91-a8a1-11c01849e498]
[16:53:36] [ServerMain/WARN]: Ambiguity between arguments [teleport, targets, location] and [teleport, targets, destination] with inputs: [0.1 -0.5 .9, 0 0 0]
[16:53:37] [Worker-Main-2/INFO]: Loaded 7 recipes
[16:53:38] [Worker-Main-2/INFO]: Loaded 1141 advancements
[16:53:40] [Server thread/INFO]: Starting minecraft server version 1.18.2
[16:53:41] [Server thread/INFO]: Loading properties
[16:53:41] [Server thread/INFO]: Default game type: SURVIVAL
[16:53:41] [Server thread/INFO]: Generating keypair
[16:53:41] [Server thread/INFO]: Starting Minecraft server on 0.0.0.0:25565
[16:53:41] [Server thread/INFO]: Using epoll channel type
[16:53:41] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing level "goldenSMP"
[16:53:47] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing start region for dimension minecraft:overworld
[16:53:49] [Worker-Main-2/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 0%
[16:53:49] [Worker-Main-2/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 0%
[16:53:49] [Worker-Main-2/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 0%
[16:53:49] [Worker-Main-2/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 0%
[16:53:49] [Worker-Main-2/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 0%
[16:53:50] [Worker-Main-2/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 0%
[16:53:50] [Worker-Main-2/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 0%
[16:53:51] [Worker-Main-2/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 0%
[16:53:51] [Worker-Main-2/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 0%
[16:53:52] [Worker-Main-2/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 1%
[16:53:52] [Worker-Main-2/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 4%
[16:53:53] [Worker-Main-2/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 4%
[16:53:53] [Worker-Main-2/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 7%
[16:53:54] [Worker-Main-2/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 9%
[16:53:54] [Worker-Main-2/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 13%
[16:53:55] [Worker-Main-2/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 21%
[16:53:55] [Worker-Main-2/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 31%
[16:53:56] [Worker-Main-2/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 50%
[16:53:56] [Worker-Main-2/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 62%
[16:53:57] [Worker-Main-2/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 83%
[16:53:58] [Server thread/INFO]: Time elapsed: 10591 ms
[16:53:58] [Server thread/INFO]: Done (16.919s)! For help, type "help"
say hi
bash: line 1: say: command not found
```

(normally, typing in `say hi` in the linux console will print `[Server] hi` in the Minecraft chat like so:

[(image of what SHOULD happen: server saying hi in the minecraft text chat)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5bvQ.png)

Comment: What do you think `bash | ` means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand;
You're logging into server as ec2-user which by default uses /bin/bash server. (I am assuming it is one of the following - Amazon Linux, RHEL, SUSE, Ubuntu as they offer the user-name ec2-user by default)

So, you do not really need to run the command "bash |" after the semi-colon symbol.

```
ssh -i "Minecraft SMP.pem" ec2-user@DNS "cd MC/Server ; java -Xmx7G -Xms7G -jar vanilla-1.18.2.jar nogui"
```

I believe it should give you the Java based MineCraft chat server you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks, I thought I tried without the bash and it didnt work, but thats probably because I didnt use a timeout command to allow the desktop to boot up before opening up the server!